# Python WebDriverException: Cannot determine loading status from no such execution context

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm web scraping in Selenium with:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])        
        WebDriverWait(driver,  
        60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#listForm > 
        div.contents_sub > div.cont_area > div > table.board_view.fix > tbody 
        > tr:nth-child(2) > td')))
```

After the new window is displayed, the following error occurs:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading
> status from no such execution context (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
> (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure the `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) `working. I mean do you really have the second window? You can print the number of windows to make sure there are 2 windows. Ideally the message seems to be occurring when you try to switch to the window which is not there.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to time.sleep before executing switch_to.window.

Comment: It was not resolved.

Comment: What’s the count/length of window handlers before switching?

Comment: I write the code that 'While True: if len(driver.window_handles)>1: break'  before driver.switch_to.window.  But It still happens often.

Answer (score 1):

`WebDriverWait` doesn't work for me also, but using `while` and `try except` block works.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

...
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

form = None
while form is None:
    try:
        form = driver.find_element_by_id('loginform')
    except WebDriverException:
        pass

print(form)
```

Additionally, I suggest trying [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem. Try to print the no. of active windows to know whether second windows is present or not. Then switch to second window. In my case second windows was not active, so i added wait and then switched.

Comment: I write the code that 'While True: if len(driver.window_handles)>1: break'  before driver.switch_to.window.  But It still happens often.